# Display and Change HTML input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PHP file where username and age are getting set. All I am trying to do right now is get their value to display it in an alert. I will be changing the values later (hence why you see the method="POST"). Right now I just want to grab the values and see what they are. But it looks like I am missing something or doing something wrong. Ultimately, I want to be able to change username, and age, and submit the form without user interaction (this is where I am really stuck). I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you very much.

In loaduser.php I have done the following:

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
<input id="age" type="number" name="age" value="<?php echo $age ?>">
```

Then in change.html I am doing the following:

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<form action="/loaduser.php" onsubmit="" method="POST">
<a href="javascript: submitform()"></a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  alert(document.getElementById('username').value);
  alert(document.getElementById('age').value);
}
</script>
</body>
```

My hunch is that I may have used this line incorrectly, but I am not sure.

```
<a href="javascript: submitform()"></a>
```

Comment: The line that is your "hunch" is totally irrelevant - its a link with no text, so you'll never see it and therefore cannot click it. Where are the two `input` fields - they're not shown in your html anywhere

Comment: `<a></a>` has no content, so it renders as a 0x0 (invisible) block. since it has NO size, it's not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without the php it looks like this. When clicked on the submit button it will post your data to loaduser.php (tip : use F12 on your browser to see network traffic / errors on page) . Good luck

```
<form action="/loaduser.php" method="POST">

  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="waarde">
 <input id="age" type="number" name="age" value="leeftijd">

 <a href="javascript: submitform()"></a>

 <input type='submit'>

</form>

https://plnkr.co/edit/rH6QunyZewm1MZbUYPAd?p=preview
```